# Can clearTimeout remove an unprocessed callback of a fired timeout event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I call `clearTimeout` for a `setTimeout` event that has already fired but whose callback is still on the execution queue, will the `clearTimeout` still prevent that event from being processed?

In other words, is it still possible to clear a timeout event during the delay of the timer firing and its callback being executed?

Informally speaking, my guess is that once the timeout fires, it queues up the callback and destroys itself – making a `clearTimeout` with that timer's id have no effect on the queued up callback.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is [yes](http://jsfiddle.net/wDdpP/).  (I'm using Firefox at the moment.)

*edit* — for completeness, the test I constructed was this:

```
var t1 = setTimeout(function() {
  clearTimeout(t2);
}, 0);

var t2 = setTimeout(function() {
  alert("hello world");
}, 0);
```

The idea is that both timers should become "ready" immediately after that script block is finished, and they should run in the order they were requested. Thus, "t1" should clear "t2" before the browser runs its callback. Because no `alert()` happens, I concluded that the `clearTimeout()` call "worked" in that it prevented the second callback from running even though it's timer had already expired.

Exactly how things work in the browser(s) is not something I'm familiar with, so there could be some situation where the `clearTimeout()` doesn't have the same effect. It seems pretty non-deterministic anyway, given the execution model.

Comment: That worked in Chrome as well. What an elegant solution. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Seems to work in Node.JS as well. My reasoning was exactly as OP's but evidently something more clever is happening under the covers :)